# Searching a specific linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Does a linear operator represented by a matrix $\textbf{O}$ exist, such that

$\textbf{O}^0\textbf{K}_n=\textbf{K}_n$,

$\textbf{O}^1 \textbf{K}_n=\textbf{K}_n \textbf{K}_{n-1}$,

$\textbf{O}^2 \textbf{K}_n=\textbf{K}_n \textbf{K}_{n-1} \textbf{K}_{n-2}$,

etc., where $\textbf{K}_n$ is an $n \times (n-1)$ matrix and $\textbf{K}_{n-1}$ is $(n-1) \times (n-2)$ and where the $i,j$'th entry in every one of them is a known $k_{ij}$ (so an entry that is in two different matrices but has the same index is the same). I.e., it should take the last matrix in it's input, crop the outermost row and column and multiply the resulting smaller matrix with the input. I'm guessing the problematic part in is the "last matrix"-thing, as I don't see how the operator could differentiate between the different matrices in it's input.

If it does exist, any ideas on how one might determine it?

**If it does not, how might one generate the same behavior in a simple way, starting from $\textbf{K}_n?$** Can one for instance use two operators in combination?

Thanks!

EDIT: Alternatively, any ideas for the cropping operator $\textbf{D}\textbf{K}_n=\textbf{K}_{n-1}$? If one had such an operator then $\textbf{O}^n\textbf{K}_n=\textbf{D}^0\textbf{K}_n\textbf{D}^1\textbf{K}_n ...\textbf{D}^n\textbf{K}_n$. I don't know if that's useful or not.

Comment: As far as I see, dimensions of $\textbf{O}^1 \textbf{K}_n$ and $\textbf{K}_n \textbf{K}_{n-1}$ don't agree: the first one has $n \times (n-1)$ and the second one has $n \times (n-2)$. Or was it "special multiplication" ?

Comment: Darn it, that is true. No, no special multiplication was intended. :(

Comment: Nonetheless I think that you can try to "embed" your matrices in regular $n \times n$ matrices by padding other elements with zeros. However, it leads to some fancy relations like $K_n K_{n-1} K_{n-2} = K_n K_{n-1} K_{n-1}$ (that's what you get if you rewrite $O^2 K_n$ as $O(O^1 K_n)$ and use other relations). However, I'm not sure that this is exactly what you wanted to do.

Comment: Hm, yes I might try that. My problem is that I have this row of matrices $\textbf{K}_n\textbf{K}_{n-1}$ and so on, and I wanted to simplify it. As there is a clear relation (although I have not found the precise, mathematical relation) between the matrices, I thought it could be simplified, but if it can't be done with a linear operator, I don't really know how to approach it.